# Jekyll: Fenced code blocks with line numbers

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to add line numbers to fenced code blocks in markdown with Jekyll.

I have tried using both `kramdown` and `redcarpet` and adding `line_numbers: true` to the `_config.yml` file (under the proper renderer config-block) but I can't seem to get line numbers on code blocks.

**Solution:**
It turned out all I had to do was to switch back to `kramdown` (default markdown renderer) and start the code blocks with `{% highlight <language> linenos %}` and the code blocks gets line numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used [this great post](https://github.com/leonardfactory/secret-blog/blob/master/_posts/2013-05-05-code-fenced-blocks-pygments-and-line-numbers-with-jekyll.md). It worked for me. As for the line numbers use,

```
{% highlight <language> linenos %}
     <code>
 {% endhighlight %}
```

Check [an example](http://ma08.github.io/It-has-begun/) on my blog and see if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer pointed me in the right direction. It turned out the problem wasn't really that complicated. All I needed to do was switch back to `kramdown` and start the code blocks with `{% highlight <language> linenos %}`.

Comment: @mbanzon  cool. Just curious, didn't the same work with redcarpet?

Comment: Using `redcarpet` I start the blocks with the tripple "hyphen" (like here on SO and GitHub) with the language/syntax to use following (with no space). Anything I've tried to put after that haven't worked.

Comment: @mbanzon Using the same syntax as in the solution should work for `recarpet` too. Also don't forget to add `pygments: true` in `_config.yml`.

Comment: I see your point (after tinkering a bit with it) - I'm glad the line numbering is working now - will decide on which renderer to use if I encounter any other trouble in the future - thank you guys for your input ;-)

Comment: That is not a new Markdown type. It works in any version of Markdown and Textile and even HTML.

Comment: The link "an example" to http://ma08.github.io/It-has-begun/ is broken

Answer (score 3):

I prefrer code fence ```` ``` ```` or `~~~` over `{% highlight %}` because markdown previewer can handle it, and also I am used to write it more natural.

The code fence can use the language as well. E.g. ```` ```java ```` will start a java code block.

I use `jekyll` v4.2 and `kramdown` with the highlighter `rouge`.

My config file `_config.yml`

```yaml
kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    block:
      line_numbers: true
```

The magic was `syntax_highlighter_opts` -> block -> line_numbers: true.

There is also an option for `<span>` elements, but I have never tried it.

```yaml
kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    block:
      line_numbers: true
    span:
      line_numbers: true
```

Answer (score 2):

As I'm in love with `pandoc` I would recommend you to use the pandoc markdown compiler:

### Add Pandoc

Install the `pandoc` compiler, e.g. on debian via `sudo apt install pandoc`.

Add this to your `_config.yaml`:

```
markdown: Pandoc
gems:
  - jekyll-pandoc
```

Then add the `jekyll-pandoc` gem to your Gemfile:

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
    # here are your other gems
    gem "jekyll-pandoc"
end
```

If you're having trouble refer to the official resources that I included at the end.

### Use Pandoc linenumbers

When you have successfully set up `jekyll-pandoc` you can use it as easy as:

```
~~~~ {.java .numberLines startFrom="1"}
class MyClassPresentedWithLineNumbersViaPandoc {
  void lineNumberedFunction() {};
}
~~~~
```

This would enable `java` code highlighting and linenumbers that start counting at `1`.

For an example of the default appearance have a look [at this listing in my blog](http://blog.hermes-technology.de/openbsd/server/virtualmachine/network/2017/06/12/vmd-for-a-virtual-server-network.html#vmd---what-goes-into-etcvm.conf).

### Official resources

[jekyll-pandoc](https://github.com/mfenner/jekyll-pandoc)

[pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)