# Fenced code block within div

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to create a Jekyll project on Github, styled with [Material Design Components](https://material.io/components/web/). MDC states that [Elements are not natively styled](https://material.io/components/web/docs/getting-started/#creating-the-skeleton-indexhtml-file), which means that most (if not all) elements will need to be styled with classes. What this means now is that

````
<div class="mdc-typography">
  <div class="mdc-layout-grid max-width">
    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
      <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-8">

      ```js
      // some js
      ```

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
````

doesn't actually render the code as expected. Rather it renders as plain text. I guess I'm a little new to this. But what is the proper way to nest fenced code blocks within `div` tags with classes?

The rule for markdown is that it *must* be indented at least 4 spaces. I am aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing this on your jekyll project use

```
{% highlight javascript %}

{% endhighlight %}
```

[Jekyll Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#highlighting-code-snippets)

Here is another stack question similar to yours: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133223/jekyll-fenced-code-blocks-with-line-numbers?rq=1)

Alternatively, you can style it like it's code.