# How to fence code blocks with line numbers correctly and update the code-block CSS

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I'm trying to add line numbers to fenced code blocks in markdown with Jekyll. Moreover, I am trying to find ways of updating the code CSS style.

Regarding the first question I am trying to follow the instructions in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133223/jekyll-fenced-code-blocks-with-line-numbers). Thus, I am trying to do two things, encapsulate the code using the following commands:

```
{% highlight python linenos %}
     <code>
 {% endhighlight %}
```

However, when I do this the code appears right after the line counter:

```
1
2
3
4
5
import os
import numpy as np
....
```

And the same behavior is occurring when I am changing in the config.yml the following lines to true:

```
# Markdown and syntax highlight
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    css_class: 'highlight'
    span:
      line_numbers: false #true
    block:
      line_numbers: false #true
      start_line: 1
```

How can I solve this issue? And in general, how can I change the CSS for only the code blocks?

EDIT:

The results after the inspection of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question consists of two issues, let's tackle them one by one.

**Adding line numbers**

There are two basic different ways of adding code line numbers to code snippets.

1. Add line numbers for specific code snippet, with

```
{% highlight python linenos %}
    <code>
{% endhighlight %}
```

2. Add line numbers for all code blocks in general:

```yaml
# _config.yml

markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    css_class: 'highlight'
    block:
      line_numbers: true #true
      start_line: 1
```

which works for code blocks generated with triple backticks: ```.

If you need line numbers in each code snippet the second approach is more useful.

**Styling**

To apply a specific style for code snippets you can utilize `rouge` [gem commands](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge?tab=readme-ov-file#command-line).

1. Install `rouge` gem locally with `gem install rouge` command.
2. Generate the stylesheet for code highlighting style of your choice with

```bash
rougify style monokai.sublime > syntax.css
```

[Here](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/tree/0f4bb7d891cb43f62bae42612ea2b6fbf67970c7/lib/rouge/themes) you can find a list of supported themes, sometimes there is more than one in a single file (e. g. in `base16.rb`)

3. Include syntax CSS file into your layout

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/syntax.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

4. Update CSS file if needed, e.g. adjust margins and paddings.

Comment: Regarding your first recommendation, I am facing the same problem, the code appears as after the line counting!

Comment: So probably this is a problem with CSS style, can you go to inspector and check how the frontend html looks like? It should be a table element, with one 'tr' with two 'td' elements inside: one for line numbers, another for the code.

Comment: I am trying to understand where exactly this tr or td is located. I have inspected the code section which appears to be from the class figure (from the html code). You can find the related code in the Edit of the post. How can I locate where this source code is generated from jekyll?

Comment: You can use "Inspect" in the browser and select html element with code block. Also, to debug if this is an issue of existing CSS styles on your page: you can quickly create new jekyll project and see if the issue with line numbers and code misalignment occurs.